# Handling Push Notification on Lock Screen ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application Push notification receives data in `json` format

Which is this

```
    aps =     {

        alert = "{\"messsage\":\"what to do when boarded \",\"chatBox\":\"130701.130693\",\"sender_id\":\"130701\",\"sender_name\":\"reg41\",\"sender_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/www.playmit.com\\/images\\/user_profile_images\\/\",\"receiver_id\":\"130693\",\"type\":\"chat\"}";

    };

}
```

[image]

But also on lock screen when app is not running or app is in background when push notification received it shows same json contents in push notification
So how do I handle this.

Thanks.

In the image Quizmatch receives push notification in `json` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to put custom tags inside aps tag. Here's what documentations says about it:

Providers can specify custom payload values outside the Apple-reserved aps namespace. Custom values must use the JSON structured and primitive types: dictionary (object), array, string, number, and Boolean.
So in your case you should do something like:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Hello World",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "Person": {
        "Address": "this is a test address",
        "Name": "First Name",
        "Number": "023232323233"
    }
}
```

Therefore you can read your custom payload with looking for it's key in main JSON, rather than in "aps":

NSLog(@"%@",notification['Person']['Address']);
Above will output:

this is a test address
You could find more about custom payloads, along with some examples in Apple docs.

Reference:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834581/ios-push-notification-custom-format)

Answer (score 0):

if user is not prevented from settings, aps.alert is always displayed

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 10,
         "alert": "Hello world!",
         "sound": "cat.caf"
    },
    "job_id": 1
}
```

update your notification structure like this, send data under some other key like "job_id"