# Displaying Message Body in Push Notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm getting follow message when I receive Push Notification and the same `JSON` is displayed to user too. I want only the `Data` to be displayed in the body when user receives the push notification rather than displaying the whole `JSON`.

under aps["alert"] I get this

```
{
   \"Type\":\"TestType\",
   \"NotificationId\":\"40\",
   \"ImageUrl\":\"\",
   \"UserId\":1,
   \"Data\":\"Testing Push Notification\"
}
```

How to display `Data` in the message body of Push Notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

     if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active) {
            if let alertInfo = userInfo["aps"]?["alert"] as? Dictionary<String,String>{

            if let title = alertInfo["Data"]{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

please try to send push notification flowing format and if application staying in background then automatic showing body message  :

```
[aps: {
        alert =     {
        body = "Testing Push Notification";
        title = "New Message";
        NotificationId= "536"
        };
        sound = default;
        }]
```

Update correct format For example

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Hello World",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "Person": {
        "Address": "this is a test address",
        "Name": "First Name",
        "Number": "023232323233"
    }
}
```

[iOS Push Notification custom format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834581/ios-push-notification-custom-format)

Comment: But how to set the title ?

Comment: I can get alert["Data"] as I have converted that to SwiftyJSON. But how to display it on Message ?

Comment: "how to display it on Message" .. where you want to display ?

Comment: On phone when app is not active. The time we received push on screen it should display that body instead of whole json object which it is currently doing.

Comment: @Nitesh you have to add "content-available":1

Comment: @JuanCurti, Nazmul Hasan So the body message is detected automatically when we get Push Notification from server(If data is in correct format) ? There is any way we set it from our side ?

Comment: @Nitesh With "content-available":1 the block is displayed automatically when the app is in background. I mean the message, when you see your apps icon, the body, the message. Just as a WhatsApp or Facebook notification. That's what you want?

Comment: @Nitesh body message is detected automatically when we get Push Notification  in app background

Comment: @NazmulHasan any way we add body from our side ? My server team is not changing response as it works for Android where they set message body content programatically

Comment: @Nitesh Format for android and ios is different so ask server team to add above specified parameter for ios notification.

Comment: Can someone please share full correct format (Including the userID and all other data which we need to push to VC) ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan Thanks, I'll get the data in this format from them.

Comment: @Nitesh could you accept the answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

> The keys in **aps** are pre-defined by apple. But you can send your **custom
>   keys** **outside aps** as shown below

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "Hey! Checkout my custom notification",
      "subtitle": "Custom notification subtitle",
      "body": "Description of custom notification"
    },
    "sound": "default",
    "category": "CustomPush",
    "badge": 1,
    "mutable-content": 1
  },
  "Employee": {
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Designation": "Manager"
  }
}
```

> Where **Employee** is custom key where you can set your own data
>   as required